# How to correctly store array of strings into array (In C)?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pipe

***Edited***

Essentially, in a program I am writing I have initialised the following:

```
char **cmd[16];
cmd[15] = '\0';
```

I then loop through an piped in text file which contains lines of text. For example, when executing the program I will run ./a.out < file.txt

Within this loop, I break each line of the file into strings and store them in `char *arguments[]`.

For example, the line of text "ls -n 5" creates `arguments = {"ls", "-n", "5", NULL}`

I then assign the pointer to arguments to an index of cmd based on the line number. I.e, `cmd[line_number] = arguments;`

My problem arises when I exit the while loop. Every index of cmd now points to the exact same thing, since what arguments points to has been changed. So even if I have a text file with:

```
ls -s1
sort -n
ls -n 5
```

cmd will contain 3 arguments, which all have the last line `{"ls", "-n", "5", NULL}`

My question is whether there's a way I can assign the current value of arguments to cmd[line_number], without the value inside being overridden in the next iteration.

The following is the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char ** cmd[16];
    cmd[15] = '\0';

    char buffer[256];

    int number_of_lines = 0;

    // Initialise arguments
    char * arguments[256];

    // Read until EOF
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {

        // tokenise buffer into arguments
        // E.g. "Hello World" => arguments = {"Hello", "World", NULL}
        parsecmd(buffer, arguments);

        // Points to arguments
        cmd[number_of_lines] = arguments;

        number_of_lines++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the parsecmd function as well:

```
void parsecmd(char *buffer, char **arguments) {

    // Get Pointer to \n in string
    char *newline = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    // Remove if found
    if (newline) {
        *newline = 0;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int token_count = 1;    
    // token equal to first to first string before whitespace in buffer
    char * token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    // While tokens remain
    while (token != NULL) {
        // Store token in arguments
        arguments[i] = token;

        // Get next token
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        // Increment counters
        i++;
        token_count++;
    } 

    // Assign all unnasigned variables to NULL 
    for (i = token_count - 1; i < 256; i++) {
        arguments[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: regarding: `{"ls", "-n", "5", "\0"}`  This would be better written as: `{"ls", "-n", "5", NULL}`

Comment: @Anthony Seager Use cmd[0] = args;
printf("%s\n", cmd[0]);

Comment: regarding: ` char *newline = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    // Remove if found
    if (newline) {
        *newline = 0;
    }`  This would be better written as: `buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: what is the value of `BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: regarding: `while (arguments[arg_count] != NULL) {
            arg_count++;
        }`   suggest the parse function return the value in the its' local variable `i`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = token_count - 1; i < 256; i++) {
        arguments[i] = NULL;
    }`  The index to the next unused index is already in `i` so suggest: `for ( ; i < 256; i++ ) {
        arguments[i] = NULL;
    }`  Of course, that is a late initialization. Suggest inserting, right after: `char * arguments[BUFFER_SIZE];`  the statement: `memset( arguments, '\0', sizeof( arguments ) );`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] rather than series of code snippets that do not compile.

Comment: where is the function: `fork_pipes()`?

Comment: `cmd[number_of_pipes] = args;` - `args` is allocated on stack, it becomes invalid after closing `}`. And all your `cmd[any index]` _point_ to the same variable `args`. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've edited my code and question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

suggest replacing:

```
printf("%s\n", cmd[0][0]);
```

with:

```
printf("%s\n", args[0]);
```

because the output format specifier: `%s` is expecting a pointer to the string, not the first char of the string